# Using \cref for algorithm step

Tags: algorithms, cleveref, algorithmic

What `\crefname` do I provide for referring to a step of an algorithm (not the algorithm float itself!)? I am able to label the steps of an algorithm and refer them using `\ref` but how do I use `\cref` with them?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us, what you try so far. The best in form of complete small document.

Answer (score 1):

Lines of algorithm can be referenced with \cref the same way as with \ref:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1] 
\State\label{foo} test
\end{algorithmic}


\cref{foo}
\end{document}
```